# how can i get posts from custom post type particular taxonomy category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I have registered custom post type Article in my template using **register_post_type**  function. and i also having  taxonomy category for this article posts.

Here i want to filter the posts under particular category. using query post

How can i do this

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters in detail it outlines everything you need. Take a look at the following code sample taken from the codex. It should help you :)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Article', /* This is where you should put your Post Type */
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bob'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Please note that this query does NOT account for paginated data.